# Tips on Activating KMS host in Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, kms

In Azure, a KMS host will be managing Office 2019 licenses for a VM Scale Set.

The KMS host requires a minimum of 5 clients with unique SID and CID to start giving out licenses. Once activated, it can go lower without issue.

Since VMs in the Scale Set come from the same image, they count as one client. The only way I got it to activate was to make 5 VM with 5 different marketplace images. This isn't very practical.

What would be the best way to activating the host in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Is it domain joined? If so, have you thought about AD based activation? So much simpler.

If not, I'd just install the MAK key on there instead of KMS key. KMS really doesn't sound like the right option if you're only running that VM Scale set against it.

Comment: It isn't domain joined. 
I tried MAK activation. When it scale up, it makes a new VM. After a certain number of activations, I was getting errors saying it hit the limit of activations.